# What does "the field will play" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A 68-team field of stalwarts, potential spoilers and national tournament newcomers will play for the N.C.A.A. championship in Division I women’s basketball.

[Source - The New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/13/sports/ncaabasketball/selection-sunday-womens-march-madness.html)

To me the text describes a 68-team field of stalwarts that will play for the N.C.A.A. championship. So how come the field will play and not the teams?

Answer (score 5):

[Field](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/field) here is a collective noun for a group of teams. The teams will play, the whole of the field will play.

> 4: The individuals that make up all or part of the participants in a contest.

Consider replacing teams and field with another singular and collective noun set.

> A 68-bird flock of parrots will race around the world.

Comment: Given OP's confusion, 'a school of fish' (perhaps 'a fish school' to keep the order) may have been a better example of a well-known collective noun.  A flock is only a flock, but a school (like 'field') has an entirely discrete meaning.

Comment: @mcalex I wanted to illustrate an example that would be straightforwards, but the school example is an excellent double meaning choice.